# Regular expression for DateTime validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to validate following date format in javascript.

> 01/26/2016 01:26:52 pm //true
>
> 01/26/2016 13:26:52 am //false

I have search on google, but not able to get regular expression which validate above date format.So please let me know how can I validate above date using regular expression.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Comment: You would not normally (should not...) use a 2 digit hour with am/pm - ie 01:26 is always 1am.   1:26 could be am or pm.

Comment: Regex is **really** not the best way of doing this, due to the hundreds of different formats.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex to validate the date is not a good idea in my opinion. You can instead try to use the Date object. Something like

```js
alert(new Date("01/26/2016 01:26:52 PM"))
```

or

```js
alert(new Date("01/26/2016 13:26:52 AM"))
```